# List all columns wtih datatype in specific table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am looking for a programmatic way to get the Snowflake table schema, is there a way for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [SHOW command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-columns.html) to list table columns e.g.

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE;
```

Note that SHOW commands have the advantage that they do not require a running warehouse to execute, so are zero cost queries.

Answer (score -1):

Use this query:

```
select ordinal_position as position,
       column_name,
       data_type,
       case when character_maximum_length is not null
            then character_maximum_length
            else numeric_precision end as max_length,
       is_nullable,
       column_default as default_value
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema ilike 'schema' -- put your schema name here
       and table_name ilike 'table'  -- put your table name here
order by ordinal_position;
```

Please note, this would incur a cost as it will require a running warehouse. If you are looking for a no-cost solution check Nathan Griffiths' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61995811/2704032). If you are looking for a query-based predictable solution you can use this answer.