# List all columns with datatype from a specific table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried the answers in this very similar question: [List all columns wtih datatype in specific table in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917196/list-all-columns-wtih-datatype-in-specific-table-in-snowflake/61995811#61995811) and they work in the Snowflake WebUI but not in Teradata SQL Assistant.

But even using SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE; doesn't give me exactly what I need. I want the query to return information like this:

```
Columns     Data Type
REGION_ID   NUMBER(38,0)
STORE_NAME  VARCHAR(20)
VALID_NAME  VARCHAR(1)
```

The data_type column from SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE; doesn't look like the above grid which is from the Snowflake WebUI ("View Details" command by right clicking the table name in left hand side of the "Find database objects" section).

The view from SHOW COLUMNS... looks like this:

```
data_type
{"type":"FIXED","precision":38,"scale":0,"nullable":true}
{"type":"TEXT","length":20,"byteLength":80,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}
{"type":"TEXT","length":1,"byteLength":4,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}
```

Yes, similar but I'm looking for something equivalent to the grid above or the Teradata SHOW TABLE command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Snowflake's [GET_DDL()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html) function.

If we create a schema and table like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA
;
CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (
  REGION_ID   NUMBER(38,0)
 ,STORE_NAME  VARCHAR(20)
 ,VALID_NAME  VARCHAR(1)
)
;
```

and then execute GET_DDL() like this:

```
SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE')
;
```

we will get output like this:

```
create or replace TABLE MYTABLE (
    REGION_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    STORE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    VALID_NAME VARCHAR(1)
);
```

Comment: Thanks Darren (again as you answered my other question (LIMIT the rows inserted...) :-).

This works but the output is all on one row/line. In the Snowflake WebUI, a simple copy to any SQL editor lists the row in a readable format, just not horizontally (not a big deal.)

In SQL Assistant, I get a 'LOB Information' pop-up box asking where and what format should the file be. Not changing anything and pressing Enter produces the normal-ish result set. clicking on the one row and column that appears launches Notepad with the result set spread out all in one row just like in Snowflake WebUI.

Comment: I changed the LOB settings in SQL Assistant and now this works just fine! The output now looks just like you posted above. Thank you!

For those wanting to know what I did; In SQL Assistant, go to Tools>>Options>>Answerset and uncheck the box for "Use default file names for LOB columns - No prompt" and press OK. Now when you run your query and the LOB prompt appears, click Cancel. The results set will now be actual text instead of a link to a file. Copy/paste that one cell to wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @rajib deb

```
show columns;
SELECT "column_name" Columns
,case when parse_json("data_type"):type::string = 'FIXED' then 'NUMBER' || '(' || parse_json("data_type"):precision::string  || ',' || parse_json("data_type"):scale::string || ')'
when parse_json("data_type"):type::string = 'TEXT' then 'VARCHAR' || '(' || parse_json("data_type"):length::string || ')'
end as Data_type
FROM (select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, PIG but this modified had the same error messages as above queries from Rajib.

Answer (score 0):

**To check columns in Table and their datatypest:**

```
show columns in table "datbase"."schema"."table_name";
# to gives the json to table attribute mapping also along with table defination
select get_ddl('TABLE', 'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE');
```

**To check columns in View of a table and their datatypest:**

```
show columns in view  "datbase"."schema"."table_name";
# to gives the json to table attribute mapping also along with table defination
select get_ddl('view', 'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE');
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you run both these queries at the same time in Teradata SQL Assistant

```
show columns ;
SELECT "column_name" Columns,parse_json("data_type"):type::string Datatype FROM (select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, Rajib but this didn't work:

show columns ;

--"Query is invalid"

Comment: Second query...SELECT "column_name" Columns,parse_json("data_type"):TYPE::string Datatype FROM (SELECT * FROM temp_cms.sm_subdiv_banner_xref (result_scan(last_query_id()))) ;
--"unexpected ("  in front of the "results_scan"